# How can I add to Python dictionary value using string keys

Tags: string, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to add string dictionary keys like this:

```
x = "%s-%s-%s %s:%s:00"%(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day,dt.hour,dt.minute)
dict[x] +=a1
```

But it gives me an error like this:

```
KeyError: '2015-11-26 8:47:00'
```

If I try `print type(x)` it prints `str`

But if i try this:

```
dict = {}
x = "abc"
dict[x] = 1
print dict
```

it print to this:

```
{'abc': 1}
```

I don't understand what is the difference.

Answer (score 4):

First error is that you named your dictionary `dict`. That name's
already being used; it's the name of the dictionary type. Overwriting an
existing name like this is called "shadowing". Don't do it, it will mess
you up.

You're using `+=`. This implies that there's already a value associated
with the key, which can be incremented. If that key isn't in the `dict`
yet, you get a `KeyError`.

You probably want to set a default value of zero. This can be done in
various ways. The simplest is:

```
d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + a1
```

Also see the `collections` standard library, which has a `defaultdict`
type.

Comment: thank you a lot. You are real life saver.by the way i didn't named  my dictionary dict.When i copied the code here i changed that.But thanks again for your warning.

Comment: @M.Witney Do feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: @TomZych after over five years he still hasn't come back to accept the answer! LOL. I gave you a plus one